# python expression to latex

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, latex

I'm trying to display equations by using GUI. I use latex and canvas. However, I'm getting an error message *ValueError: KeyPress event keysym=Return keycode=36 char='\r' x=266 y=8*

it should be working because I have already converted python expressions into Latex's.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from sympy import *
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()

frame1= Frame()
frame1.pack()
caracter=StringVar()

def  result(caracter):
    a = str(caracter)
    text1=latex(a)
    ax.clear()
    ax.text(0.2, 0.6, "$"+text1+"$", fontsize = 6)  
    canvas.draw()



def element(num):
    caracter.set(caracter.get()+num)

#-----------------------------SCREEN------------
screen=Entry(frame, width=50, textvariable=caracter)
screen.pack()
screen.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=5)
#-----------------------BUTTONS-----------------------
go=Button(frame, height=1, text="Go")
go.grid(row=1, column=6)

Buttonx=Button(frame, text="x", width=5, padx=0, pady=2, command=lambda:element("x"))
Buttonx.grid(row=2, column=6)

#--------CANVAS ---------------    
label = Label(frame1)
label.pack()



fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=label)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

root.bind('<Return>', result)



root.mainloop()
```

This is the shortest code to reproduce the issue. Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the char associated with `<RETURN>` to your function `result`. Because the parameter is named `caracter`, this shadows the variable `caracter` declared earlier as a `tk.StringVar`.

something like this should give you the expected result:

```
def result(dummy_c):
    a = caracter.get()
    text1 = latex(a)
    ax.clear()
    ax.text(0.2, 0.6, "$"+text1+"$", fontsize = 6)  
    canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot and yes, I can see the equation now.

Comment: I was looking for those guidelines. I will follow them from now on. Thank you.